# to write a select query which strictly satisfies a multiple condition on same column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to write a select query by joining  two tables.
like this..

```
select entityid from  companytagrel left join taginfo on companytagrel.tagid=taginfo.tagid where taginfo.tag = "own" and taginfo.tag ="rocking";
```

where the relationship between tables companytagrel and taginfo are N->1
i want to select the entityid which strictly satisfy the condition that its taginfo.tag is own and rocking.

> note: A company can have any number of tags.

```
companytagrel's column->(uniqueid,entityid,tagid)
taginfo's column -> (tagid,tagname)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the entities having both a 'own' tag and a 'rocking' tag? Or do want those that have exactly 2 tags: 'own' and 'rocking'?

Comment: exactly those two(rocking,own)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select ct.entityid
from companytagrel ct left join
     taginfo t
     on ct.tagid = t.tagid
where t.tag in ('own', 'rocking')
group by ct.entityid
having count(distinct t.tag) = 2;
```